# Android Studio doesn't finish to build while using ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm working on an Android Studio project made by someone else which uses ORMLite.

When I try to build the project the process arrives in :app:createORMLiteConfigDebugFile and then never comes to an end or give me an error and runs forever.

I've never used ORMLite so i don't know where to start to look for a solution.

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: What error does it give?  Can you edit your question and provide more information?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error, the program simply never ends to build. It stays on the :app:createORMLiteConfigDebugFile action forever without ending it